# I changed localhost to also be "m", but my browser tries to go to m.com everytime. How can I prevent this?

Tags: firefox, browser, apache-http-server, localhost

To save precious typing, I've set it up so "localhost" is also "m". For example,  http://localhost/phpmyadmin is also http://m/phpmyadmin.

This is on an apache serer, I use Firefox and this works on my Mac, but doesn't on Arch Linux. When I type literally http://m/phpmyadmin it takes me to http://www.m.com/phpmyadmin. I don't know if it's a browser setting or a httpd.conf setting.

I've tried removing the value for `browser.fixup.alternate.prefix` and `browser.fixup.alternate.suffix`, but now it just searches for that string.

How can I fix this?

edit: `ping localhost` works as expected, but `ping m` returns `ping: m: Name or service not known`

Comment: Of course it is. It can't find `http://m/`.

Comment: You say «I've set it up so "localhost" is also "m".»  What do you mean? What have you done? Can you offer any evidence to suggest that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ping shows that `m` is not resolving.

Edit `/etc/hosts` and add `m` to the end of the line that reads (it may have other names after localhost, just add a space to the end and `m`):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Exit and ping `m`.  If that works, return to your browser.  It may have cached the negative response from earlier so you may need to restart it.

Comment: Ah yes! `/etc/hosts`, how could I forget. Thanks Paul.